# SBT - Transitive dependency clash

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I am building a library `L` at my company for an old project `P` that we cannot touch.

The library is bringing a dependency `Dv3` which have an incompatible version with something that the old project is using `Dv1`.

How can I build `L` so it is hiding `Dv3` from `P` ? I know it is probably not good practice but there are not many options here.

Thank you